PyCharm with Snakemake refuses to recognize correct working directory
I have a project that uses Snakemake with the following files: Project/envs/config.yaml and Project/workflow/Snakefile. I have installed SnakeCharm. I want Snakemake to access this config file. At the top of the Snakefile, I have written:
configfile: "../envs/config.yaml"
PyCharm refuses to recognize this as a valid path. It indexes from Project/ instead of Project/workflow. Projects is in my Documents folder (Documents/Projects) so it looks for a file at Documents/envs/config.yaml, and says "Unresolved Reference." If I resolve it with "Create File", it makes a file at Documents/envs/config.yaml, which I don't want.
Image of project error in Pycharm
I have tried the following:

Invalidating caches & restarting
Deleting & recreating the project
Removing and re-adding the Python interpreter
In Project Settings - Project Structure: Setting the only Source Folder to be either workflow/ or Project/
Verifying in Modify Run Configuration that the Snakefile's Working Directory is workflow/

Is there any way to resolve this? I have attached the specific error. I apologize if this has been answered elsewhere; I looked as thoroughly as I could but could not find this specific issue.

"../envs/config.yaml" only references the intended file if you assume that the current working directory is "Project/workflow", which is evidently an incorrect assumption.  "envs/config.yaml" looks like it would work.

Thank you for your comment! I understand that ../envs/config.yaml only references the correct file if the working directory is the workflow/ folder. When I run the Snakefile, it correctly uses that working directory, so the functionality is good. I am trying to figure out how to get Pycharm to recognize that as the working directory rather than visually giving me an error.
